# Is this statement about four variables a,b,c, and d correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b=\frac{h}{c-d}$ and h is an arbitrary nonzero constant, $a<b$, and $c>d$, does this imply that $a-b=\frac{h}{c+d}$?

Comment: No. How about you try a simple example? For example, let all variables be positive, then $a+b \gt 0$, but $a-b \lt0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a + b =\frac{h}{c - d}$, then $h$ isn't an "arbitrary non-zero constant": the equation holds iff $h = (a+b)(c-d)$. Likewise $a - b =\frac{h}{c + d}$ iff $h = (a-b)(c+d)$. $(a+b)(c-d)$ is not equal to $(a-b)(c+d)$ in general, so the suggested implication is false.

Answer (score 0):

No:

$2+3=\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{5}} = 5$

$2-3\neq\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{5}} = \frac{5}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
P(h, a, b, c, d) = (a + b = h / (c - d)) \wedge (a < b) \wedge (c > d) \\
Q(h, a, b, c, d) = (a - b) = h / (c + d)
$$

If $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c= 4$, $d=2$ then
$$
P(h,1,2,4,2) = ((1 + 2) = h / (4 - 2)) \wedge (1 < 2) \wedge (4 > 2)
$$
is only true for $h = 6$.

In which case the statement
$$
Q(h, 1, 2, 4, 2) = (1 - 2 = h / (2 + 4) = h / 6)
$$
would be false. Then the implication
$$
P(6, 1, 2, 4, 2) \Rightarrow Q(6, 1, 2, 4, 2)
$$
is false.

This ruins the larger statement, which I interpret as
$$
\forall a, b, c, d: \forall h>0: P(h,a,b,c,d) \Rightarrow Q(h,a,b,c,d)
$$